# Validation algorithm in checkout field

Tags: php, functions, woocommerce-offtopic

|G| |YY| |MM| |DD| |CC| |ZZZ| |C|

|C| - control digit

|ZZZ | - order number assigned to a person

|CC| - country code

|DD| - day of birth

|MM| - month of birth

|YY| - year of birth

|G| - gender (M/F) for :

1/2 - Romanian citizen born between 1 ian 1900 and 31 dec 1999

3/4 - Romanian citizen born between 1 ian 1800 and 31 dec 1899

5/6 - Romanian citizen born between 1 ian 2000 and 31 dec 2099

7/8 - residents

9 – people with foreign citizenship

**Preliminary step:** To test if the code respects the format of a personal identification number code.

It means that the first digit must be in the limit 1-6 or to be 9 for foreigners.

The following 6 digits must form a calendar date validated in the format `YYMMDD`.

**Step-1:** Use the testing key “279146358279". The first twelve digits multiply by one from left to right with the corresponding digit from the testing key.

**Step-2:** The twelve digits resulted gather together and the obtained sum divides to 11

If the rest of the division to 11 is less than 10, then this will represent the control digit

If the rest of the division is 10, then the control digit will be 1

For a validated Personal Identification Number the control digit must be the digit on the postion 13 of the initial Personal Identification Number

Now I need is to implement this logic in the woocommerce framework, in a checkout field to ensure that user gave me the correct identification id and I have no idea how to implement it.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to learn WordPress Plugin development, especially how to use WordPress Hooks: https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/hooks/

Then, you need to learn how to implement Woocommerce specific hooks: https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/introduction-to-hooks-actions-and-filters/

Finally, use appropriate Woocommerce hook to filter & validate Personal Identification Number provided by the user according to your algorithm.

Since it's not clear at what stage you are receiving those Personal Identification numbers, you need to check [Woocommerce hook reference](http://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/hook-docs.html) to find and implement appropriate hook for your use case.